# Problem with Zabbix docker nginx datetime

Tags: nginx, locale, zabbix

I have a zabbix server based on a docker-compose-new.yaml

For all event the reported time is one hour ahead.
So when are 10:54 I see in graph (and event) 11:54

I added Timezone to my yaml script:

```
version: '3.5'
    services:
     zabbix-server:
      image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:centos-4.2-latest
      environment:
       - "TZ:Europe/Rome"  <--
      ports:
       - "10051:10051"
```

I added in all image that script launch

- zabbix-server:
- zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:
- zabbix-snmptraps:
- zabbix-agent:
- mysql-server:

also in the container zabbix-web-nginx-mysql I set in the file /etc/php.ini date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"

restarted nginx..... but nothing!

DTS?

what i can do? Hoq I can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a week of attempts (many online solutions all based on Apache) I solved by **overriding** the global setting of **php.ini** (already set to the correct value) adding in **/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php**
the option

**date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe / Rome');**

Reading around I found several posts which say that it is necessary for the **web component** to "**reiterate**" the settings related to the **timezone**

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix 5.0.2 virtual appliance

Here's my solution:

1. Change time zone

   ```
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime
   ```
2. Find file `zabbix.conf`

   ```
     find / -name zabbix.conf
   ```
3. Edit file `zabbix.conf`. In my case:

   ```
    /etc/php-fpm.d/zabbix.conf

    vi /etc/php-fpm.d/zabbix.conf
   ```
4. find inside

   ```
    php_value[date.timezone] = Europe/Warsaw
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to solve it.

First I found docker-compose.yaml.

and then I put in the time zone I need at the moment.

```
environment:
          - TZ = America/Sao_Paulo
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).